# How to compute the Pareto Frontier, intuitively speaking?

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I'm working on a [multi-objective optimization problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization) and we have 'alternatives' that are quantified on two dimensions - value and cost.

Now the question is 'how does one compute a pareto frontier'? I mean I know you can *apply algorithms* that will do it for you, but I want to know the basic underlying algorithm/mathematical-steps that would be employed to come up with a pareto frontier - I want to be able to do it with pen and paper - even if the *algorithm* is NOT efficient.

I looked all over and it seems I only stumble upon various algorithms that can be employed but not the actual intuition behind how does one compute a Pareto frontier in the first place!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The basic definition of the Pareto frontier is that it consists of exactly those alternatives that are *not* dominated by any other alternative.  We say that an alternative $A$ dominates $B$ if $A$ outscores $B$ *regardless* of the tradeoff between value and cost — that is, if $A$ is *both* better *and* cheaper than $B$.

Obviously, both the best and the cheapest alternative always belong to the Pareto frontier, and in fact, they are its endpoints.  A simple algorithm to find the other alternatives (if any) on the Pareto frontier is to first sort the alternatives according to one of the objectives — say, cost.  One then starts with the cheapest alternative (which, as noted, always belongs in the Pareto frontier) and skips successive alternatives in order of increasing cost until one finds one with a higher value.  This alternative is then added to the frontier and the search is restarted from it.

A step-by-step description of the algorithm, assuming that $A_1, \dotsc, A_n$ are the alternatives in increasing order of cost, goes like this:

*Algorithm A*:

1. Let $i := 1$.
2. Add $A_i$ to the Pareto frontier.
3. Find smallest $j>i$ such that $\operatorname{value}(A_j) > \operatorname{value}(A_i)$.
4. If no such $j$ exists, stop.  Otherwise let $i := j$ and repeat from step 2.

---

#### Addendum

In the comments below, Nupul asked about computing the Pareto frontier for combinations of alternatives.

There are two natural and interesting cases: one where the combinations are sets of alternatives (i.e. each alternative may appear at most once in a combination), and one where they are [multisets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) (which can include the same alternative more than once).  I'll address both cases below, but let me first give an alternative algorithm for computing the Pareto frontier for *single* alternatives:

*Algorithm B*:

1. Let $A_1, \dotsc, A_n$ be the alternatives sorted in order of increasing cost/value ratio.  Let $i := 1$.
2. Add $A_i$ to the Pareto frontier $P$.
3. Find smallest $j>i$ such that $A_j$ is not dominated by any alternative already in $P$.
4. If no such $j$ exists, stop.  Otherwise let $i := j$ and repeat from step 2.

In step 3, to check whether $A_j$ is dominated by any alternative in $P$, it will suffice to find the most expensive alternative $B \in P$ which is still cheaper than $A_j$.  (Of course, by symmetry, we could also choose $B$ as the least valuable alternative in $P$ that has higher value than $A_j$.)  If $B$ does not dominate $A_j$, neither can any other alternative in $P$.

Algorithm B is somewhat more complicated than algorithm A above (in particular, algorithm A runs in $O(n)$ time *if* the alternatives are already sorted, whereas algorithm B needs $O(n \log n)$ time in any case), but it turns out to generalize better.

---

Now, let's consider sets of zero or more alternatives.  Obviously, we could just enumerate all such sets and then apply algorithm A or B, but this would be very inefficient: for $n$ alternatives, the number of sets is $2^n$.  Instead, we can adapt algorithm $B$ to construct the combinations on the fly:

*Algorithm C*:

1. Let $A_1, \dotsc, A_n$ be the alternatives sorted in order of increasing cost/value ratio.  Let $i := 1$.  Let $P := \lbrace\emptyset\rbrace$, where $\emptyset$ denotes the combination containing no alternatives.
2. For each combination $C \in P$, let $C^* := C \cup \lbrace A_i \rbrace$.  If $C^*$ is not dominated by any combination already in $P$, add $C^*$ to $P$.
3. If $i = n$, stop.  Otherwise increment $i$ by one and repeat from step 2.

Again, as in algorithm B, we don't need to compare $C^*$ to every combination in $P$; it's enough to check whether $C^*$ is dominated by the most expensive combination in $P$ that is cheaper than $C^*$.

---

What about multiset combinations?  In this case, obviously, the Pareto frontier $P$ contains infinitely many combinations: in particular, for any combination $C \in P$, the combination $C + A_1$, where $A_1$ is the alternative with the lowest cost/value ratio, also belongs in $P$.

However, the number of times any *other* alternative can appear in a non-dominated combination must be bounded.  (The proof is a bit tedious, but follows from simple geometrical considerations.)  Therefore we only need to consider the finite set $P_0$ of those combinations on the Pareto frontier which do *not* include the alternative $A_1$; the remaining combinations on the frontier are obtained by adding some number of $A_1$s to those combinations.

For multiset combinations, we also have the following useful lemma:

**Lemma:** *Any combination that contains a dominated sub-combination must itself be dominated.*

In particular, this means that combinations in $P$ can only include alternatives that themselves belong in $P$.  Thus, as a first step, we can use algorithm A (or B) to compute the Pareto frontier for single alternatives and discard any alternatives that are not part of it.

For a complete algorithm to compute $P_0$, the following definition turns out to be useful:

**Dfn:** A combination $B$ is said to $A$-dominate $C$ if the combination $B + nA$ dominates $C$ for some non-negative integer $n \in \mathbb N$.  Equivalently, $B$ $A$-dominates $C$ iff $\operatorname{cost}(C) > \operatorname{cost}(B) + n\,\operatorname{cost}(A)$, where $n = \max \left(0, \left\lfloor \frac{\operatorname{value}(C)-\operatorname{value}(B)}{\operatorname{value}(A)} \right\rfloor \right)$.

Using this definition, we can apply the following algorithm:

*Algorithm D*:

1. Let $A_1, \dotsc, A_n$ be the (non-dominated) alternatives sorted in order of increasing cost/value ratio.  Let $i := 2$.  Let $P_0 := \lbrace\emptyset\rbrace$.
2. For each combination $C \in P_0$, let $C^* := C + A_i$.  If $C^*$ is not $A_1$-dominated by any combination already in $P_0$, add $C^*$ to $P_0$.
3. Repeat from step 2 until no more combinations are added to $P_0$.
4. If $i = n$, stop.  Otherwise increment $i$ by one and repeat from step 2.

I *think* this algorithm should be correct, but to be honest, I'm not 100% sure that there aren't any mistakes or gaps in my proof sketch.  So please test it thoroughly before using it for anything that matters. :-)

I also think it should be possible to implement step 2 efficiently in a manner similar to algorithms B and C, but the situation is complicated by the fact that the rejection condition is $A_1$-domination rather than simple domination.  Of course, if $B$ dominates $C$, then it trivially $A$-dominates $C$ for any $A$, so one can at least first do a quick check for simple dominance.

Another way to optimize step 2 is to note that if $C + A_i$ is $A_1$-dominated by any combination in $P_0$, then so will be $D + A_i$ for any combination $D$ that includes $C$ as a sub-combination.  In particular, we can skip to step 4 as soon as we find that $\emptyset + A_i = A_i$ itself is $A_1$-dominated by some combination already in $P_0$.

Comment: Now isn't that lovely - short, sweet and simple! +1 for that. What about computing the Pareto-frontier with combining alternatives? What you suggest would only be for a single alternative. What if multiple alternatives could be combined (values of *value* and *cost* being additive)? How would you compute it in that case?

Comment: Nevermind - I guess I figured it out - you'll have to create an exhaustive list of all possible combinations of the alternatives and *then* run the above algorithm. I guess now I understand what the other fancy algorithms must by doing since it's exponential in complexity! So simple yet so confounding! Thanks a ton!

Comment: If I understand you right, you should be able to simplify things a bit. Note that any combination involving a dominated alternative must itself be dominated; thus, you can first compute the Pareto frontier for the single alternatives, and then only consider combinations of those alternatives. (In fact, I suspect you can simplify this even further, but I'll have to think about it a bit more.)

Comment: Ps. Are your combinations sets or multisets?  That is, can I include the same alternative more than once in a combination?  (The question is interesting either way, but knowing which case you're primarily interested in would help in writing an answer.)

Comment: The combinations are sets. In my context including the same alternative twice makes no sense :) - it is either pursued/implemented/done or it isn't

Comment: OK, I expanded my answer to cover combinations of alternatives too.  In fact, it turns out that the set-combination case seems to be simpler; even though the multiset case has the nice lemma I mentioned above, it has other complications that seem to make it harder to handle than I thought at first.

Comment: Brilliant! Quite frankly, brilliant!! Thanks a ton!!