# How to compute the pareto frontier for dimensions higher than 2?

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I'm looking for an intuitive way to compute the pareto frontier for dimensions higher than 2, i.e. a generalization of this (very nice) solution: [How to compute the Pareto Frontier, intuitively speaking?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101125/how-to-compute-the-pareto-frontier-intuitively-speaking)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the algorithm in [Ilmari's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/101141/6622) recursively. Sort along some direction $x$, and for each value of $x$, beginning with the best, add the $(n-1)$-dimensional Pareto frontier (computed recursively) of the items with that value of $x$ to the $n$-dimensional Pareto frontier, then ignore or remove all items dominated by the added items.